# Close all Activities when the app returns from being in the background

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

It is important in my app that when a user presses the home button and the app enters the "Background" the app reverts to the login screen next time it is opened.

I have tried using the

```
 android:noHistory
```

in the manifest but this means when pressing back on activities it reverts also to the login screen so is no good. I have also tried using

```
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```

in my initial activity but this doesn't seem to have any effect. I don't finish() the first activity so i am not sure why this doesn't work.

Can anyone help with a way of doing this.

Comment: Why is it important? It looks like you don't understand how Android works and are trying to actively work against it. Apps are not "closed" by home button. Also Android has this principle of keeping the illusion that apps are actually never closed - they should appear always open and ready to be used, that's why you usually ask for login once and store it for example in account manager.

Comment: wow, this is important because for security if the app enters the background and a non user gets hold of the device and tries to open the app it should revert to the login screen, so it is very important as the data contained within the app is sensitive data , i clearly state in the question title about the app being in the background so you knew exactly what i meant by saying "closed" but i will edit it if it is not clear. FYI not all apps that login have the same functionality so to say apps should ask for login once and store is a huge assumption

Comment: PS i am not here to work "against" android i simply have a requirement of the app, so your comment there is highly inaccurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by using

```
 android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```

Turns out that I didn't have it in my root activity, this was because I have a second login screen which asks for less details depending on if you have logged in before.

Although it works exactly as i want it to, apparently using this "Android" feature is incorrect because i am going "against" android by clearing the tasks (activities) when the home button is pressed and my app should follow someone else opinion of what an "app" should do. Who Knew!

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use the onPause()-Method?  This should be called every time the Activity gets in Background.

So something like:

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

Due to the fact that only one Activity of your App can be active at a time you don't have to worry about others still being active.

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm, FYI just missing the super.onPause(); Thanks!

Comment: This is a **bad** idea. Any dialog (or additional Activity) will cause onPause() to be called and close your App. You should be using the [launchMode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) option in the manifest.

Comment: It should also have the same problem as `noHistory`, namely: "when pressing back on activities it reverts also to the login screen so is no good"

Comment: your right yes, sorry Marcel, not the answer i was looking for.  Would i use "singleTask" @adelphus ? Can you write an answer